# getDate() does not return the exact date that system have?

Tags: android

i am implementing custom listview in android with image, text and date but when i call getDate  method it will work but return 1/1/1970 instead of showing my system date?

Comment: This issue means the time is coming up as `0` (January 1, 1970 is 0ms from the Unix Epoch). Can you show some code? How you populate the list, and how you fetch the date?

Comment: Returning "January 1st 1970" is *not* well summed up with "does not return the exact date" .. (That is, something is just wrong. And it's likely not the API/runtime.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `new java.util.Date()` and it will contain the actual date. You can also use `Calendar.getInstance()` or `long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); new Date(time);`

Answer (score 2):

FYI,
[getDate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getDate%28%29) => **This method is deprecated**. And it returns the day of the month.

You can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  // you can mention any format which you want
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND)
```

[android calender documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
here is the complete solution.where you can get the date and also access it in the form of string.


private final static String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss");
        Log.i("Log", "date is:  "+df.format(new Date()));
        return df.format(new Date());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
DateFormat date  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss");
    Log.i("Log", "date is:  "+date.format(new Date()));
    date.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();

String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(new java.util.Date(dtMili));
```